# Is there a way to move my Steam games to a new Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, steam

I recently got a new Xbox 360 and I was wondering if there is a way to move my Steam games (specifically Assassins Creed, Half-Life, Portal) to the Xbox hard drive. Perhaps I could redeem them for a hard copy somehow?

Answer (score 14):

Games do NOT transfer from Steam to Xbox as a legit version. Once you purchase a game from Steam, it is only available on [Steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1313-QIPD-5381).

Even if you did move your games over to your Xbox hard drive, you would still need a hard copy disc that is specifically made for Xbox to run the game. There are ways to burn Xbox discs but they are very illegal.

If you were looking to play [Steam games with an xbox360 controller](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1445-TKCN-0831), you can on [select few games.](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1325865) You can also browse Steam store for titles with [full](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?snr=1_4_4__12&term=#category2=28&sort_order=ASC&page=1) or [partial controller support](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?snr=1_4_4__12&term=#category2=18&sort_order=ASC&page=1).

Comment: There are talks of having steam clouds shared with consoles in the future but as far as I know this only applies to PS3 consoles and steamwork games. So as TrickyM66 mentioned your kinda outta luck on this one, but I would enjoy this if It was possible one day aswell.

Comment: *There are ways to burn Xbox discs but they are very illegal.* Manufacturers all over the world are breaking the law! I knew it! ;-)

Comment: There's not even a way to download Xbox content using Steam, so you won't even have anything you can burn or copy to an Xbox.

Comment: @JamesGecko Im talking personal use. Obviously he is not planning on mass producing these to sell.

Comment: @Ward: Steam Cloud is game data (saves etc.) not the actual games themselves.